# Apache, mod_authz_host, ineffective 'Allow from' clause

Tags: apache-2.4, ip, hostname, mod-authz-host

I am trying to restrict access to a part of my website to only a specific machine within the local network using `mod_authz_host`.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html

My config looks like this:

```
<LocationMatch "/export.*">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from 192.168.1.207
</LocationMatch>
```

where `192.168.1.207` is the IP address of the machine I want to allow access.

The problem is that the access from the machine is still denied.

In the log the access looks like this:

```
fvs318gv2 - - [27/Mar/2018:15:42:28 +0200] "GET /export/ HTTP/1.1" 403 209
```

EDIT: The corresponding log format used is: `"%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"`

which makes me wonder what `fvs318gv2` means, it doesn't even look like an IP address? Obviously, Apache is not seeing the machine as coming from its IP address, where could be the problem?

If I do `ipconfig /all` on that machine, I get:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ****
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter PýipojenĄ k mĄstnĄ sĄti:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : EC-A8-6B-81-87-60
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c4be:bf88:60e3:f97b%7(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.207(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : pondŘlĄ 26. býezna 2018 16:10:21
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : stýeda 28. býezna 2018 10:49:43
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 250390635
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-4B-5D-B6-EC-A8-6B-81-87-60
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Belkin Wireless Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : EC-1A-59-D8-1F-18
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter PýipojenĄ k mĄstnĄ sĄti* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : EC-1A-59-D8-1F-18
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter PýipojenĄ k mĄstnĄ sĄti* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : EC-1A-59-D8-1F-18
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:850:262d:2a57:4513(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::850:262d:2a57:4513%3(Preferred) 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 167772160
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-4B-5D-B6-EC-A8-6B-81-87-60
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop using 2.2 directives please:

```
<Location /export>
  Require ip 192.168.1.207
</Location>
```

Note: I also modified your location for a less complicated method without regex since you seem to request /export/kkk

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't make any difference.

Comment: @MartinVlk didn't make a difference to what, what do you get? This is the only way to allow only a specific ip.

Comment: I have explained the problem above - do I need to improve the question so that the problem is more clearly laid out?

Comment: You could share the log format you are using for example to find out what those weird values are.

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster replied, apache-2.4 uses other directives to change requirements.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html

With regards to the IP-filter itself you will have to double check which IP you *actually* come from.

Take a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html
The LogFormat string you use has `%h` which is the hostname apache is able to lookup from the client IP.

If you add `%a` you will also get the clients IP-address. NB! See note about `mod_remoteip` **if** you use that directive.

HOWEVER, what I suspect is that you run this apache server on the same host you are trying to access it from, could that be the case? If so you **might** be routed through localhost --> See `Require local` in the apache docs.

If that is not the case, it **might** be that you are routed over IPv6, which has a different format for it's IP-addresses. `mod_authz_host` also handles IPv6, see the docs for examples.

Modifying the `LogFormat` to include `%a` **will help you**, example:

```bash
LogFormat "%h(%a) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
```

PS! Converting from `apache-2.2` to `apache-2.4` is documented in the docs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

PS! `tcpdump` is a handy tool to have in your toolbox for any and all network related problem solving. ymmv.